# Inserting Environmental Variables into Auth0 Hosted Pages

Tags: environment-variables, auth0

I have three different tenant environments for my development, rc and live Auth0 login pages.

Each has a Google Tag Manager script in the `<head>`,

In all other applications I'm able to define the Analytics ID in an environment variable and then insert it into the template to ensure that my live login analytics only to go the live google analytics etc.

My dual question is:

- On Auth0 Hosted Pages, how do you write in a variable into the template?

I've tried every combination of `@@my_variable@@`, but I cannot get anything to insert other than it representing my variable name as a string!

- Once I can call variables from within hosted pages, where is the recommended place to call a variable from that doesn't need to be a secret (i.e. Google Analytics IDs)?

Currently I've got mine defined in tenants -> environments, but again it's not clear from the documentation if you can call that into a hosted page template in Auth0.